# After upgrading PHP to version 7, why can't I use the mongodb driver?

Tags: linux, mongodb, php-7

Well here's an odd situation I've found. I've been using PHP and MongoDB together on a project, and updated the associated software. After the upgrade, I did make sure to update the new conf files and all is well --- except when I try to use the `MongoClient` class, I get the following fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in /srv/http/test.php

So my first instinct was to check my `/etc/php/php.ini` to make sure that mongodb.so was correctly included. I found it after the other `extension` lines:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=zip.so
extension=mongodb.so ; <--- here it is
```

With that checked, I loaded up a quick `phpinfo()` script to check that I was using the right `php.ini` file, and confirmed that I am. And not only that, the mongodb driver also appears to be loaded correctly!

```
Loaded Configuration File      /etc/php/php.ini
. . .
mongodb support                enabled
mongodb                        version      1.1.1
mongodb                        stability    stable
libmongoc                      version      1.3.1-dev
libbson                        version      1.3.0
```

So I restarted httpd and tried again. No dice, still can't find the `MongoClient` class. So I tried to install it from `pecl` instead of my distribution's package manager, and the situation is the same as described above.

---

So here's a quick rundown of the situation:

- Linux kernel 4.3.3
- PHP Version 7.0.1
- php-mongodb version 1.1.1

  - Yes, [1.1.1 supports php7](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.1.1).
- Seems properly configured, and mongodb is enabled and shown in `phpinfo()`.
- Tried installing the mongodb driver through `pecl` and my distro's package manager.

Other info that may be useful:

- MongoDB Version 3.2.0
- `mongod` is running
- Also tried rebooting, no change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I found the answer.

The class has been changed. It's no longer `\MongoClient`, and is now `\MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

All that I need is a refactor. The new driver is designed to be a lower-level driver for high-level functionality to be filled with userspace libraries, so anyone else upgrading to php7, make sure you check that you'll be comfortable with the new driver, or that the userspace libraries exist when you do it. Hopefully this question/answer helps others in the future.

Commenter ianaz below has posted this good userspace library for MongoDB: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/

Comment: are they serious?! here a userspace library: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/ . Thanks :)